# Trying to change the order of my blog category content?

Tags: wordpress, layout, blogs, categories

Currently the content is displayed: Image, Title, Content.

I would like it to be Title, Image, Content.

My page is here:

http://luminationcapital.com/editorial-avada/

The file I am trying to edit is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/btrkjyn8s4vkv6j/class-blog_save%202.php?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. In your code you will see 3 items:

1. the_title();
2. the_content();
3. the_post_thumbnail();

`the_title();` displays the title of the post.
`the_content();` displays the content of your post (editor).
`the_post_thumbnail();` displays the featured-image of your post.

You must order these manually to be what you please.

`function loop_header`, the entire section, should come first.

`function get_post_thumbnails`, the entire function, should go second.

etc.

It is clear that you are in over your head with the amount of PHP involved. Take it slow, test, and make sure you move around the entire function stack without leaving anything out.